# ERROR webdriver: Request failed due to Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver-io

Struggling to get `browser.dismissAlert()` working on WebdriverIO. It's like having an alert dismissed or not, confuses webdriver with what port or window or something is being used by which port.

```
ERROR webdriver: Request failed due to Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
For context:
```

Context:

- e2e tests run fine - they open a browser window
- create a sign-up account,
- confirm email account
- come back to the main webapp
- Then in mid-flow, they try to refresh the page and are hit with an alert('Are you sure you want to reload? You will lose all your saved information') - user is given an "OK" or "Leave" option.
- At that point we were dismissing it and continuing through the flow.
- But now whatever we try, it breaks with the above error.

Code:

```
 it('should try to re-load the page afresh and click `leave` to abort', () => {
    browser.pause(1000);
    browser.url('http://localhost:3000/signup/page-to-refresh-on'); //reload page
    console.log('==== this logs out ===='); // at this point alert is showing
    browser.dismissAlert(); // attempt to dismiss it
    console.log('==== this does not log out ===='); // never reach this point, error logs out
    browser.pause(2000);
    assert.equal(true, true)
  });
```

I have tried:

1. browser.keys(['Escape'])
2. browser.dismissAlert()
3. browser.acceptAlert()

They all fail with the error after a test that involves confirmation alert.

Env:
node 10.17.0
"chromedriver": "^85.0.0",
MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide a reproducible example? `dismissAlert` does work for me.

Please note that `dismissAlert` only works for native alerts.
You can handle custom alerts like regular DOM elements.